# Append images to existing video using OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv

Is it possible to open existing video file using cv2.VideoWriter and just append new images?
If not, what is the best solution here?

Comment: What do you mean by *"append"*? Will appending an image make the video wider? Or taller? Or longer duration? Images also aren't video, so how do we know the duration each one should stay on the screen for? Why use OpenCV and Python? Why not just use `ffmpeg`?